# 1111 (HY000): Invalid use of group function | Not able to use group function in THEN PART OF QUERY

Tags: mysql

In below query I am not able to use

```
THEN count(DISTINCT(workflow_link.email_api_response_packets.parent_id))
```

syntax, Any help is appreciated here.

```
SELECT workflow_link.email_api_response_packets.subscriber_id
     , count(DISTINCT(workflow_link.email_api_response_packets.parent_id)) as cnt
     , SUM(CASE WHEN (workflow_link.email_api_response_packets.action = 'O'
                      AND workflow_link.email_api_response_packets.parent_id IS NOT NULL
                THEN count(DISTINCT(workflow_link.email_api_response_packets.parent_id))
                ELSE 0
                END)*100/SUM(CASE WHEN (workflow_link.email_api_response_packets.id
                                        AND workflow_link.email_api_response_packets.parent_id IS NULL)
                                  THEN 1
                                  ELSE 0
                                  END) AS percentage
FROM workflow_link.email_api_response_packets
WHERE workflow_link.email_api_response_packets.updated_at >= 1403929223
    AND workflow_link.email_api_response_packets.updated_at <= 1503929479
    AND workflow_link.email_api_response_packets.list_id IN (400)
    AND workflow_link.email_api_response_packets.is_test = 0
GROUP BY workflow_link.email_api_response_packets.subscriber_id
HAVING percentage >= 0
```

Comment: have you tried       count(DISTINCT workflow...)  ?  (ie without inner brackets)

Comment: There's a problem with your brackets in the first `CASE WHEN`: You open it after the `WHEN` part but close it after the `END`. So there's a bracket missing after `IS NOT NULL`.

Comment: @etsa, thank you for comment I have tried suggested way, but no luck same error

Answer (score 0):

Try this pls.  I removed all unnecessary brackets too.

```
SUM(CASE WHEN workflow_link.email_api_response_packets.action = 'O'
              AND workflow_link.email_api_response_packets.parent_id IS NOT NULL
         THEN count(DISTINCT workflow_link.email_api_response_packets.parent_id)
         ELSE 0 END
    ) * 100
      / SUM(CASE WHEN workflow_link.email_api_response_packets.id 
                      AND workflow_link.email_api_response_packets.parent_id IS NULL
                 THEN 1
                 ELSE 0 END) AS percentage
```

Comment: I think you can't do the construct SUM( COUNT(..) ).  So you have to rewrite your query.  If you post a simpler structure with create/insert scripts and a similar query, I can try to help you.